# Draw A Stack of Shapes

Tags: html, canvas, svg, webgl

I'm trying to build a web tool to generate an image composed of a stack of shapes. Each shape element is derived from one original shape; the derivation is basically created by expanding by *x* pixels, then rotating it by *y* degrees, then placing it at the "end" of the stack. In the picture below, the original shape is a white heptagon, with slightly curved sides. The pink derivation was created by the following steps:

1. Copy the white heptagon and enlarge it by 10 pixels.
2. Rotate it by +/- 8 degrees.
3. Place it behind the white heptagon.

My question is what web technology will be suitable (and the simplest) to do this task? HTML5 canvas, SVG, or WebGL? I am leaning towards the canvas but it [only supports one primitive shape i.e. rectangle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Tutorial/Drawing_shapes?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Canvas_tutorial/Drawing_shapes).

For the curvy sides, I don't think there is a library that does this automatically. I might need to resort to doing it manually e.g. using *arcs()* in canvas.

[image: A stack of shapes]

Comment: HTML5 supports polygon.. So, with a little bit of research you can make it work

Answer (score 1):

**Here's code to draw a stack of concentric rotated poly-arc shapes**

[image]

This code lets you define the number of sides in your polygon as well as the inset size of your arcs.

This code just stacks the shapes from bottom-to-top, but you can always use ctx.globalCompositeOperation="destinationover" to draw behind the current shapes.

Here is code and a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/KkteA/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
    $(function(){

        var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

        drawArcInsetPolygon(7,100,.8,200,150,2,"gray","pink",-90);

        drawArcInsetPolygon(7,100,.8,200,150,2,"gray","white",45);

        function drawArcInsetPolygon(sideCount,size,arcInset,centerX,centerY,strokeWidth,strokeColor,fillColor,rotationDegrees){
            var radians=rotationDegrees*Math.PI/180;
            ctx.save();
            ctx.translate(centerX,centerY);
            ctx.rotate(radians);
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo (size * Math.cos(0), size *  Math.sin(0));          
            for (var i = 1; i <= sideCount;i += 1) {
                  var cpX= (size*arcInset) * Math.cos((i-.5) * 2 * Math.PI / sideCount);
                  var cpY=( size*arcInset) * Math.sin((i-.5) * 2 * Math.PI / sideCount);
                  var endX= size * Math.cos(i * 2 * Math.PI / sideCount); 
                  var endY= size * Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI / sideCount);
                  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(cpX, cpY, endX,endY);
            }
            ctx.fillStyle=fillColor;
            ctx.strokeStyle = strokeColor;
            ctx.lineWidth = strokeWidth;
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.restore();        
        }

    }); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=400 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your question was quite interesting--regular polygon with an arc twist!  Did you find this answer useful?

Answer (score 1):

Canvas should be very capable of allowing you to easily clone, alter and redraw elements behind your drawings :).

For something simple, as of Mar 2013, I'd recommend using [Kinetic JS](http://kineticjs.com/)

Blobs would get you arched sided polygons easily like this:

```
new Kinetic.Blob({
    x: 200,
    y: 200,
    scale: 2,
    offset: [50, 50],
    points: [{
        x: 36,
        y: 0
    }, {
        x: 81,
        y: 10
    }, {
        x: 100,
        y: 50
    }, {
        x: 81,
        y: 90
    }, {
        x: 36,
        y: 100
    }, {
        x: 0,
        y: 73
    }, {
        x: 0,
        y: 27
    }],
    fill: '#AAFFDD',
    strokeWidth:0.2,
    tension: 1.1
});
```

> (Link for historical purposes only, It no longer works)
>   Check It in a fiddle~ jsfiddle.net/jaibuu/VUzKP/